# Custom Event Error "Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 1."

Tags: actionscript-3, events, actionscript

I'm currently making a basic custom event class that passes just one piece of data.

```
package {
import flash.events.Event;

public class DateEvent extends Event {

    public static const DATE_SET: String = "exampleEvent";

    public var calendarObj: Object;

    public function DateEvent(type: String, calendarObj: Object = null) {

        this.calendarObj = calendarObj;

        super(type, false, false);

    }

    override public function clone(): Event {

        return new DateEvent(type, calendarObj);
    }
}}
```

When calling the event like so:

```
selectedDate = new Date(displayedYear, displayedMonthNum, displayedDate, displayedHour, displayedMins);
        trace(selectedDate);

        dispatchEvent(DateEvent(DateEvent.DATE_SET, selectedDate));
```

I'm getting an "Incorrect number of arguments" error. I'm quite confused as I'm not passing any more than what I'm supposed to (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `new` keyword before the call to the `DateEvent` constructor. Like so -

```
dispatchEvent(new DateEvent(DateEvent.DATE_SET, selectedDate));
```

Comment: That's it! I can't believe I forgot to add that. Thank you!